# Visual Studio 2012 always starts up with a maximized window, how do I prevent it?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2012, startup, behavior

I always exit Visual Studio when its main window is at a certain area on the screen. But when it starts up, its window is always maximized. If I click the maximize button, it is restored to the size I left it in previous session.

It is bothersome to do this at every program start-up. It covers the area of the screen which it isn't supposed to; making other tools working on that area stay behind. And what makes it even more cumbersome is the bulky and slow start of Visual Studio.

Is there any way of setting the start up window size and position? It is like, in somewhere an option "Start main window maximized" is checked, but I can't find such a thing under *Tools > Options*. Visual Studio 2010 did do this behavior.

Version: Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate 11.0.51106.01 Update 1
Theme: Dark

Comment: How are you launching Visual Studio? Are there any arguments on the shortcut you are using?

Comment: @ChrisF I'm launching it with a shortcut. In the properties of that shortcut, under the "Shurtcut" tab, "Run:" is set to "Normal window".

Comment: Have you checked if there is anything relevant in the "CurrentSettings.vssettings" file in "C:\Users\currentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings"?

Comment: Oddly I have the opposite problem, it never opens maximized or snapped-to-half-screen even if that was its last state.